# How to go about emulating this type logo

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, typefaces

I have been trying to create a similar type logo to this one (Hyper3D):
[image]

I’ve followed a few examples online, but my best result so far has a lot of room for improvement.

This is my best attempt as of now (Dark Phoenix):
[image]

Please disregard the curved lines pattern, as it should be vertical lines - I was following an online tutorial. In any case, the resultant type logo still needs work. I will try again, with vertical straight lines, and adjusting the line thickness, with thinner lines closest to the left and right sides of each letter, and thicker lines towards the middle of each letter. The font being used is `Sofia Pro Soft`

Also, this is the superb tutorial, from this graphic design exchange, that I followed:
[Tutorial](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/112711/how-was-this-distorted-line-text-effect-achieved)

Thank you all, in advance! I appreciate it.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You seem to have answered your own question - "I will try again with vertical straight lines . . .".  So, what are you asking exactly?  To get the blurring effect? Use a blur.

Comment: Something like this [example](https://imgur.com/NdaI2jk)

Comment: Thank you Billy Kerr. It has been suggested, elsewhere, to perhaps use Astute graphics and halftone. I’ll also use the blur effect, as you’ve suggested. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see why you'd need to use astute graphics for this TBH, as Illustrator is entirely capable of doing something like this on its own.  Other possibilities might include using Photoshop for more complex blurring, especially since the intention is to create a raster image, then trace it in Illustrator.