# How can I create a halftone using rough lines?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, line-art

Does anyone know if is there an effect to make something like the following images with photoshop? I thought it was halftone lines but this lines aren't straight.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. These aren't the same effect. The top one can be made. using the halftone pattern filter in Photoshop. The other is an amalgamation of a cut-out piece over a background and not a single "effect".

Comment: This old case https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/99785/create-engraving-in-gimp-inkscape contains also your halftoning problem with curved lines. There are also many more old cases of the same problem. Package "Filter Forge" contains a fake engraving filter for this. With Photoshop alone you must build a little for curved lines. The second image is a composition as already said by Mr. Kerr.  It can be drawn easiest in a vector program like Illustrator. There you can have strokes with non-uniform widths. There are  also ready to use brushes for this.

Comment: To me the first image just looks like ordinary halftone lines which has been distorted somehow. You could use *Filter > Distort > Displace* to give the lines that wobbly feeling. That would also distort the image itself, but this could be counteracted by also applying the *inverse* displacement before adding the halftone lines. Some manual inconsistencies could be added at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your advices guys!

Comment: @Scott, I don't agree that this is a duplicate. The duplicate is about creating a classical engraving effect with lines following the shapes. This seems more like standard halftone lines with a worn wobbliness to them. I was just writing an answer. 

Comment: I added more dupes @Wolff -- Note, as I read it, this question is **not** about trying to fix any of the samples, but rather reproduce something similar.. and there are several duplicates related to that (More than I'm allowed to add in fact.) In addition, theres no real effort in this question.. it's a fly-by "how do I do this".

Comment: @Scoot, I've looked through the 5 examples and can't really see how they are similar to the effect in the top image. And I can't see how the answers would help to recreate the effect in the first example here (I'm ignoring the second example as it isn't the same effect and doesn't fit the OP's description). These are straight halftone lines which are distorted a bit which I would show how to do using a displacement map.

Comment: @Wolff https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/101175/3d-lines-effect-in-illustrator-photoshop (scroll down) But if enough vote to reopen or a mod does.. then that's that. I still feel it's a duplicate unless the question is edited to show more effort and detail.

Comment: @Scott OK, I disagree. I will have to see what others think.  The answers you link to show how to make lines follow the shape of the figure in the image. I see this more as a kind of grunge effect. The width of the lines change to make different tints. Some unevenness is added to give it a handmade feel.

Comment: But that's only if you are viewing the Bowie image... not the second image.. what if the user *really* wants the second image effect? There's no way to know. And this is why I linked to *many* dupes... all with varying methods and results.

Comment: @Scott Fair enough. If the user removes the second image and focus on the worn effect in the Bowie image, I hope the question can be reopened and then I have an answer ready.

Comment: @RafailAntoniadis Can you clarify if you want the effect to be like the one on your first or second screenshot?

Comment: @curious♦ I'm interested for both effects.I thought for the 1st one was used halftone lines but the effect it's a little different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two examples you've posted show two very different things. The first one is clearly an effect applied to an image. The second one is a manually constructed vector drawing. There is no real trick to that, it's just to draw the shapes (if you can imagine them).

Here is some inspiration for making something similar to the first example.

### Distorted halftone lines using Displace filter

I will use this image by Piotr Siedlecki (CC0 Public Domain).

[image: Original image]

I will create halftone lines by converting to *Bitmap mode* which has no anti-aliasing so I start by scaling the image up 400%, so I can later scale it down to 25% to get an anti-aliased result.

Then I create a displacement map at the same size of the upscaled image and save it as a separate file. It could look like this (here I used *Filter > Render > Difference Clouds* and manipulated them a little):

[image: Displacement map]

I apply the displacement map to the image by using *Filter > Distort > Displace* with the following settings:

[image: Displace settings]

Now the image has been distorted a little bit:

[image: Distorted image]

I then use *Image > Mode > Bitmap* with the following settings to create the halftone lines:

[image: Bitmap settings] [image: Halftone Screen settings]

These settings will have to be adjusted to fit the resolution of your image and the number of lines you want.

The result is a distorted image with straight halftone lines:

[image: Halftone lines applied]

Now I use *Image > Mode > Grayscale* to enable the use of filters. I apply the displacement map once more, but this time with negative values in *Horizontal Scale* and *Vertical Scale*:

[image: Final result]

The image itself is no longer distorted, only the halftone lines:

[image]

You can paint in some manual defects if you like and the image can be scaled down to its original size.

Comment: Initially I was wondering why you were using displacement at all, but the -20, -20 displacement is a nice touch, Wolff.

Comment: I think that second example made by hand. Thanks for your answer! 