# How can I distort the pattern of parallel lines in shape, simulating volume? Using Illustrator, Photoshop or any weird tool you know

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes, path-effects

I need to distort the pattern of parallel lines in shape, simulating volume. The work should be in vector. Attach a pic of smth likely I want to do:

[image: img with lines pattern]

But I want to do it with any shape, not only type. I've struggled a bit with Illustrator, but wasn't successful. For example, I can't envelope lines around compound path (thats I need)

If someone knows how to do it, it would be wonderful! ヾ(•ω•`)o

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46ihT_nkGyU

Comment: See this related question [3d lines effect in illustrator or photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/101175/3d-lines-effect-in-illustrator-photoshop)

Comment: @JulianSteinmann Thank you! It seems to be what I've been looking for!

And thanks for other answer